# How to fix ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'odoo.report' error in odoo 12

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-12

I have a module I am trying to port from odoo 8 to odoo 12 and I get this error when installing it in odoo 12 environment

```
 File "/home/akoh/Documents/erpsoftapp/isn_addons/report_xls/report_xls.py", line 33, in <module>
    from openerp.report.report_sxw import report_sxw
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/modules/module.py", line 110, in load_module
    mod = importlib.import_module(canonical)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'odoo.report'
```

This is the package import generating the error

```py
from openerp.report.report_sxw import report_sxw
```

And this is the code block that is using the imported package

```py
class report_xls(report_sxw):

    xls_types = {
        'bool': xlwt.Row.set_cell_boolean,
        'date': xlwt.Row.set_cell_date,
        'text': xlwt.Row.set_cell_text,
        'number': xlwt.Row.set_cell_number,
    }
    xls_types_default = {
        'bool': False,
        'date': None,
        'text': '',
        'number': 0,
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to download this module from github  " reporting-engine " and add it to your addons repository 
I wish this will help you